# Linux FIND searching files with names within single quotes

Tags: linux, awk, path, find, single-quotes

I am trying to save results of FIND command into array so then I can do some AWK commands with them.

My actual code is: `files_arr=( "$(find "$1" -type f \( -name "\'*[[:space:]]*\'" -o -name "*" \) -perm -a=r -print )`

- this code should find all files with spaces and without spaces and return them to my array (and are readable also)

The PROBLEM is,  when I have directory named: **'not easy'** and inside this is directory are files: **'file one'** and **'file two'** 
 so what I will get is: **not easy/file one**

what I want to get is: **'not easy'/'file one'**
I was thinking about using SED to add quotes but it would add quotes even if I had just simple one word file which doesnt have quotes in it.

**Thank you for our advices.**

Comment: Why do you need the single quotes around the slash `'/'`?

Comment: ... or anywhere?

Comment: It was my mistake, it didnt have to be exactly in that style, I just needed to have special characters ignored.
Thanks to you all I have solution, have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Try this out :

```
mapfile -d '' files_arr < <(find . -type f -name "'*[[:space:]]*'" -perm -a=r -print0)
declare -p files_arr # To see what's in the array
```

Comment: thank you sir, this helped me a lot, it works.
FINAL CODE IS:   ```mapfile -d '' files_arr < <(find "$1" -type f \( -name "\'*[[:space:]]*\'" -o -name "*" \) -perm -a=r -print0)```
This find all files, normal and also those with special characters in it.